# Who do you think {will be the next president/the next president will be}?

Tags: word-order, questions

I was debating with someone on the internet and suddenly we came across this topic. I know the second sentence sounds odd and this is a bit silly to ask, but grammatically is it still acceptable somehow? And if yes do they have the same meaning?

> Who do you think will be the next president?

VS

> Who do you think the next president will be?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say they're both correct and both mean the same thing.

There's an argument that the second example should be "**Whom** do you think...", but if so it's not worth worrying about.

Consider:

> Do you think she will be the next president?

VS

> Do you think the next president will be her?

The second (rather clunky) example is written in the passive voice and uses the objective case pronoun.